# Why isn't my service deleted on uninstall? (WIX)

Tags: wix

Even after a reboot, the service is still there, even though the executable file is gone. I'm using WIX version 3.0.5419.0

```
<Component Id="IdiomServer.exe" Guid="7a751e1e-5e9e-41d2-be60-dc905ab1ccad">
  <File Id="IdiomServer.exe" Source="$(var.IdiomServer.TargetDir)IdiomServer.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
  <ServiceInstall Id="IdiomServer_Service" Name="IdiomServer 4.0" Account="LocalSystem" Description="Idiom Repository Server" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" />
  <ServiceControl Id="IdiomServer_Service" Name="IdiomServer 4.0" Remove="uninstall" Stop="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
```

Installing the Windows Service works fine. Uninstalling it appears to do nothing. Section of the log file from the uninstall:

```
MSI (s) (D8:5C) [09:43:58:033]: Doing action: StopServices
MSI (s) (D8:5C) [09:43:58:033]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:43:58: StopServices.
Action ended 9:43:58: StopServices. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:5C) [09:43:58:033]: Doing action: DeleteServices
MSI (s) (D8:5C) [09:43:58:033]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:43:58: DeleteServices.
Action ended 9:43:58: DeleteServices. Return value 1.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have an almost identical installer that works fine.  The only differences are that my ServiceControl element has a different Id to the ServiceInstall element, and a 'Start="install"' property too.

I suspect your problem is either the Id of the ServiceControl element, or you have a stray service hanging around.

Try the following:

- Change the ServiceControl Id to "IdiomServer_ServiceControl"
- Change the Name in both Service elements to "Foobar" and check if the Foobar service is both installed and uninstalled.  If that works, you may just need to manually delete the stray IdiomServer entry with the "sc" command.

Comment: Close. The problem was not the IDs but the Component/@Guid. Once I changed that, uninstall works fine.
The Guid for the service component apparently needs to be changed along with Product/@Id when creating a new version of the product.

Comment: That is not true. Changing the Component/@Guid means all the resources contained in the Component must change as well. This is an MSI restriction commonly referred to as "Component Rules". You will see very bizarre upgrade and uninstall behavior when changing Component/@Guids.

A verbose log file of the original uninstall should show why the ServiceControl did not delete your service.

Comment: See Rob's blog entry, http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/Component-Rules-101, for a description of why changing the Component Id without changing the resources is a bad thing.

Comment: This ^
You should really know what you're doing if you're going to change Component/@Guids. Doing that can make MSI upgrade not work as expected, GUIDs are used for the upgrade and if it finds a component with a different GUID it removes it.

Comment: Here is a non-broken link for Rob Mensching's Component Rules 101: https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/component-rules-101/

Comment: I want to second Rupert's observation that changing the GUID of the component resulted in the service being uninstalled as I expected. I see Rob's comment that this shouldn't be done. Yes, my ServiceInstall and ServiceControl names match.

Answer (score 14):

I also had a similar problem. In my case, I just had to make sure that both ServiceInstall and ServiceControl's "Name" attributes are the same, and the problem went away.

Comment: I've just spent 2 days trying various things with wix and the windows installer trying to track down strange behaviour (including no uninstall of service) with a service using the MajorUpgrade element. After making umpteen changes to my Wix file, I spotted this, realised I had the same issue, changed the names, removed all my other changes and it all works fine! If I could vote up more than once I would! :)

Comment: this was the reason I was failing. Now I look at - of course it seems obvious. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue of the service not deleting.  I had copied the Component, Service Install and ServiceControl elements from another project without changing the Guid or IDs.  After updating with new GUID and IDs the service now deletes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to that described by Rupert.  In my case the service was not uninstalled from the Service Control Manager and the .exe was also left behind.  After much digging the answer was pretty straightforward.  In the containing <Component> element the GUID attribute was set to "" (i.e. empty string).  Replacing with <Component ... GUID="56CD2588-B976-4198-B815-FAB7E1E57CD7" > resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

If changing the component guid worked, I'd suspect that the issue might relate to an erronous SharedDLL ref counter in the registry at : **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls**

These are legacy style reference counters that MSI can increment (if asked to) - and they will override the MSI's own reference counting. For some dumb reason Installshield increments the legacy ref count for all files (whether they are versioned or not), and this frequently makes for mysterious "stray files on uninstall" occurring on development pcs. The same can occur in Wix if you enable the shared dll ref count and in rare cases the ref count can get corrupted during major upgrades.

Comment: Hi Stein, what do you recommend to fix this? Changing the component GUID results in the expected behavior for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Ie uninstalling removed everyhing BUT the entry in the services list (Win 7 - local admin). First I installed from a network share and that was when the uninstall didn't complete. When copying the installation program to a local disk before installing, then the uninstall worked just great!